# How to change an attribute in Shapefile with a certain value with QGIS / Python

Tags: python, gis, shapefile, qgis

I want to use the Python Console in QGIS to change all attributes in a Shapefile with a certain value.
I have a field named "ANB" and I want to change the value "2" in for example "3".

I know how to access the layer and select the values I want:

```
layer=QgsVectorLayer("C:.../Briefkasten.shp","briefkasten","ogr")

selection=layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(u' "ANB"=2'))
```

But I don't know how to proceed.

Can someone help me?
Thank you very much!

Greetings Robert

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to change all the entries where "ANB"=2 to "ANB"=3. Is that right? And selection may contain more than one occurrence of "ANB"=2, yes?

Comment: In case my guesses above are correct, I would think that your selection variable will have a list attribute containing the entries found by getFeatures(). You can see the attributes of selection by doing "dir(selection)" and then doing "select.<attrribute-name>" to see an attribute's value. You need to find the one that has the list you're interested in. I hope this helps. I'm not familiar with QGIS, but I'm telling you in general how Python objects typically behave.

Comment: Yes Tom, you understand it correctly. Thank you very much!
I will post the code below in case someone has a similar problem.

Comment: Good job, Robert! You answered your own question. :)

Answer (score 4):

With the help of Tom I figure out the correct code (comments in german, sorry for that)

```
#####Vektorlayer (Shape) in QGIS laden:

layer=QgsVectorLayer("C:/Users/robert 2/Documents/QGIS_Python/Briefkasten.shp","briefkasten","ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])


#####Attribut aus Shape abfragen

layer=QgsVectorLayer("C:/Users/.../QGIS_Python/Briefkasten.shp","briefkasten","ogr")
features=layer.getFeatures()
f=features.next()
f.attributes()

##Index von bestimmten Spaltennamen finden um den später ansprechen zu können (ANB beinhaltet dann Index als Zahl) 
ANB=f.fields().indexFromName('ANB')

## nur ein bestimmtes Attribut aus einer Spalte auswählen und anzeigen lassen
selection=layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(u' "ANB"=2'))

## selektierte Werte updaten:

layer.startEditing()
for feat in selection:
  layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), ANB, 3)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: the use of this method is described here: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.changeAttributeValue